# How to limit what records are sent to Algolia?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algolia

Using Algolia in Ruby on Rails, I can easily index a model:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AlgoliaSearch

  algoliasearch per_environment: true do
    attributesToIndex ['name', 'canonical_url']
    attributes ['name', 'canonical_url]
    add_attribute :type do
      "Service"
    end
  end
end
```

Is there some way to limit which `Service` I want sent?

For example: `Only index Services where name != nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's definitely possible to do:
https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails#restrict-indexing-to-a-subset-of-your-data

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AlgoliaSearch

  algoliasearch if: :name? do
  end

end
```